# Scilab 6.02 app bounces but doesn't open up in MacOS BigSur

Tags: macos, installation, scilab

I have installed Scilab 6.02 version in MacOS BigSur earlier after disabling the gatekeeper and it was working fine. However, after sending it for repair, I lost the application and have been trying to reinstall the app again. But even after disabling the gatekeeper, while trying to open it, the app bounces in dock but isn't opening up. This problem is not seen with other applications. Can someone help me out?

P.S: I don't have much knowledge when it comes to coding and other technical aspects. I am trying my best to understand, so I hope the answers would be in simplistic terms

Answer (score 0):

Please install the branch-6.1 version at

[https://www.utc.fr/~mottelet/scilab_for_macOS.html](https://www.utc.fr/%7Emottelet/scilab_for_macOS.html)

unless you have a particular reason to still use 6.0.2 (I don't see any). Another point: please remove any JRE or JDK (in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/) you had before and let Scilab dowload the required one.

S.

Comment: The same problem occurs int the 6.1 version as well